# timings problems in hackerrank in “Beautiful Triplets” question

Tags: java

I am solving the "Beautiful Triplets" problem may be my logic is correct but it is showing the timings problems The Question is given below in image.My solution for same is given below. It contains only given function ***beautifulTriplets(int d, int[] arr)*** which is returning integer and accepting two values one is **d** and **second is array of integer**. Some cases are runnning but some are showing timings error.

The question is

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd9YY.png)

The solutions for same is

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    // Complete the beautifulTriplets function below.
    static int beautifulTriplets(int d, int[] arr) {
        int i,j,k,beautifulTripletsCount=0;
        for(i=0;i<(arr.length-2);i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<(arr.length-1);j++)
            {
                for(k=j+1;k<(arr.length);k++)
                {
                    if(i<j&& j<k)
                    {   
                        int j_i_Difference=arr[j]-arr[i];
                        int k_j_Difference=arr[k]-arr[j];
                        if(j_i_Difference==k_j_Difference && k_j_Difference==d)
                        {
                            beautifulTripletsCount++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return beautifulTripletsCount;

    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        String[] nd = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(nd[0]);

        int d = Integer.parseInt(nd[1]);

        int[] arr = new int[n];

        String[] arrItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int arrItem = Integer.parseInt(arrItems[i]);
            arr[i] = arrItem;
        }

        int result = beautifulTriplets(d, arr);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedWriter.close();

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the input array always sorted? It is sorted in the given example.

Comment: @Eran yes it is sorted

Answer (score 1):

Your solution of 3 nested loops has a running time of `O(n^3)`.

You can improve it to `O(n^2)` as follows:

1. Let `i` go from `1` to `arr.length - 2`. Find the number of beautiful triplets in which `arr[i]` is the middle element:
2. Iterate from `i-1` down to `0` to count how many elements are equal to `arr[i] - d`
3. Iterate from `i+1` up to `arr.length - 1` to count how many elements are equal to `arr[i] + d`
4. Multiply the two numbers you found in the previous two steps and add the product to the total number of beautiful triplets.

This will give you a total running time of `O(n^2)` even if the input array is not sorted.

If the input array is sorted, you can do better, since steps 2. and 3. can be done with binary search, and therefore take `O(logn)` instead of `O(n)`. This will give you a total running time of `O(nlogn)`.

The version for general (unsorted) arrays:

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    int first = 0;
    int third = 0;
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (arr[i] - arr[j] == k) {
            first++;
        }
    }
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[j] - arr[i] == k) {
            third++;
        }
    }
    result += first * third;
}
```

Comment: how have you found out its complexity which is O(n^3) can u tell me plz

Comment: @niladrimandal are you asking about the complexity of your solution or my solution?

Comment: complexity of my solution

Comment: can u tell me plz how to find out the complexity of the problem or give me the reference of the document so that i can read same

Comment: @niladrimandal try to compute the number of times your `if(i<j&& j<k)` condition will be evaluated. Due to the 3 nested loops, it will be a function of `arr.length ^ 3`. Hence the `O(n^3)` running time.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to improve timing was to make one loop and find in the array the indexes j and k base on adding d to the value at position i and j. I used binarySearch implementation from java.

```
    int count = 0;
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int j = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, arr[i] + d);
        if (j > 0) {
            int k =Arrays.binarySearch(arr, arr[j] + d);
            if (k > 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
```

Comment: This helped me improve the time and solve the question. I borrowed it to write it in C#. Not many differences and easy to understand! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my accepted solution for BeautifulTriplets on HackerRank.

```
import java.util.List;

public class BeautifulTriplets {
    public int beautifulTriplets(int d, List<Integer> arr) {
        int size = arr.size();
        int beautifulTripletsCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 2; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size - 1; j++) {
                if (arr.get(j) - arr.get(i) == d) {
                    for (int k = j + 1; k < size; k++) {
                        if (arr.get(k) - arr.get(j) == d) {
                            beautifulTripletsCount++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return beautifulTripletsCount;
    }
}
```

And here is the test case with 2 sample inputs.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;

class BeautifulTripletsTest {

    @Test
    void shouldReturnCountOfBeautifulTriplets() {
        BeautifulTriplets beautifulTriplets = new BeautifulTriplets();
        Assertions.assertEquals(3, beautifulTriplets.beautifulTriplets(3, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10)));
        Assertions.assertEquals(2, beautifulTriplets.beautifulTriplets(3, Arrays.asList(1, 6, 7, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 19)));
    }

}
```